# What is the default subject of an rspec view spec?

Tags: rspec

Given an rspec view spec for Rails,

```
RSpec.describe "plots/show", type: :view do
  describe "displaying inoculation" do
    context "inoculated" do
      it "displays 'Yes'" do
        assign(:plot, build(:plot))
        render
        expect(rendered).to have_content("Inoculated? Yes")
      end
    end
  end
end
```

When I try to use the implicit subject style with `it {}`,

```
context "inoculated" do
  before do
    assign(:plot, build(:plot))
    render
  end
  it { is_expected.to have_content("Inoculated? Yes") }
end
```

The test fails with *expected to find text "Inoculated? Yes" in "inoculated"*.

I expected that the implicit subject would be the view, but instead, the subject is the String passed to `context`. Why don't view specs have the view as the implicit subject of the spec?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not related to view specs. When determining default subject, it tries to locate a class reference in the chain of nested describes. Takes the innermost class, if found. If not found, it takes the innermost value (a string, presumably).

```
RSpec.describe User do
  describe 'foo' do
    describe 'bar' do
      it { puts subject }
      it { puts subject.class }
    end
  end
end

RSpec.describe 'User' do
  describe 'foo' do
    describe 'bar' do
      it { puts subject }
      it { puts subject.class }
    end
  end
end

RSpec.describe 'User' do
  describe Project do
    describe 'bar' do
      it { puts subject }
      it { puts subject.class }
    end
  end
end
```

#### Output

```
#<User:0x007fe77593af80>
User
bar
String
#<Project:0x007fe7924f9170>
Project
```

It all starts here, btw (if you're inclined to do some digging too):

```
From: /Users/sergio/.gem/ruby/2.4.1/gems/rspec-core-3.6.0/lib/rspec/core/memoized_helpers.rb @ line 57:
Owner: RSpec::Core::MemoizedHelpers
Visibility: public
Number of lines: 6

def subject
  __memoized.fetch_or_store(:subject) do
    described = described_class || self.class.metadata.fetch(:description_args).first
    Class === described ? described.new : described
  end
end
```

Comment: Added more results. :)